# Why does the system clock run a lot faster than the hardware clock on Linux?

Tags: linux, clock

I got a bizarre problem which is the system clock always runs a lot faster than the hardware clock. For example, I set both system clock and hardware clock to20:00. After about 15minutes later, the system clock will probably run to20:17, while the hardware clock remains correct, which is20:15.

Comment: Can you please post the specific C code?

Comment: You do not mention your hardware specifications, or your Linux distribution and kernel version. Without this information it's hard to answer.

Comment: This question would also be better suited for SuperUser.com

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, and there is no C code. The problem is just the system clock always runs faster than the hardware clock on my Linux server. No matter I adjusted it repeatedly. It just runs faster.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder16.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Tue Nov 3 16:18:27 EST 2009

Comment: Since the hardware clock runs correctly, I think the hardware specification is not necessary.

Comment: Check clock skew on linux on this SF question http://serverfault.com/questions/183298/testing-clock-skew-of-multiple-servers

Comment: I think the problem is similar to http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/system-clock-vs-cmos-clock-112198/

Comment: Are you running Linux as Guest System (Virtualized)? If yes, check this article -> (vmware only, but the kernel parameters could help) -> http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427

Answer (score 2):

There might be an NTP daemon running, which will gradually adjust the system time to the world time.  As far as I know, the system time is written to the hardware clock only on shutdown.

Comment: There is no NTP daemon running.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a linux system install the command / package "adjtimex" (In Ubuntu, it's called this way). The command adjtimex gives you access to the kernel time variables and provide you with further hints what's the situation or problem on your system.

You might also take a look into the "hwclock" manpage which discusses a lot of things that might lead you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your CMOS battery may be running out; try replacing it.

Comment: The hardware clock is fine! Only the system clock runs fast.